# Reading single from textbox

Tags: .net, vba, textbox

Here is my Sub:

```
    Protected Sub PrincipleTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Try
        principle = Single.Parse(PrincipleTextBox.Text)
        PrincipleTextBox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Empty
        ResultLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
        ResultLabel.Text = "hi"
    Catch ex As Exception
        PrincipleTextBox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Pink
        ResultLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
        ResultLabel.Text = "Money values only for principle"
    End Try
    PrincipleTextBox.Text = FormatCurrency(principle)
End Sub
```

I want to read in a real number for principle and some elementary warnings if it's not a real number in the textbox.  So, I type in 225 and it doesn't work (see image).

Why?

Thanks again for any answers to what I'm sure is an elementary question...still learning...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inform the Parse method about the presence of the currency symbol of a particular culture

```
Dim info = New CultureInfo("en-US")
Dim principle = Single.Parse(PrincipleTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, info)
```

However, being the input typed by your user, you should approach the conversion problem with a more defensive attitude. If your user manages to write something that cannot be transalated to a number then it is preferable to use

```
 Dim principle as Single
 Dim info = New CultureInfo("en-US")
 If Not Single.TryParse(PrincipleTextBox.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, info, principle) Then
     ' Code for invalid number input instead of catching the exception
      PrincipleTextBox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Pink
      ResultLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
      ResultLabel.Text = "Money values only for principle"
 Else
    PrincipleTextBox.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Empty
    ResultLabel.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
    ResultLabel.Text = "hi"
End If
```

and avoid an expensive *drive-by-exception* logic

Comment: Mostly very useful information, I had not even thought of someone putting in a currency symbol.  No, I got my error with just a simple 225 as the input.

Still, TryParse looks promising.  Let me see what I can see...thanks so far!

Comment: Removing the exception handler and letting the code crash with a meaningful error message should be the next step trying to understand what's going on and why a simple valid numeric text cannot be converted by the Parse call

Comment: I've discovered already that the .Text isn't changing, so while I type '225 enter' the program is trying to parse '$0.00' and failing (I haven't tried the CultureInfo yet).  I'm not sure why the Enter key isn't changing the text field.

Comment: Do you set the PrincipleTextBox to zero at the Page_Load event? Are you testing for the Postback flag in the Page_Load event? Remember that the Page_Load event triggers before every server side event, not just the first time you load the page.

Comment: I see now.  I commented out my Page_Load sub and it started working normally.  Now I need to:
- Learn more about Page_Load
- Decide if it's necessary

Thanks a million!